# Increment value of bash expression

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a file called `export_list` that has 8 values on separate lines. I am looking to make another file, that echoes the values. For some reason I cannot find the write expression to increment the line value of sed. Any help is appreciated.

export_list looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I have an import file that looks like this:

```
count=1
if [ $count -lt 8 ]
        then
                value=$(sed -n ''$count'p' < export_list)
                echo $value
                ((count++))
fi
```

Comment: Maybe you're trying to learn `sed`, which is good, but I'd create an import_file with the following contents `cat export_file` :)

Comment: Also, I think you're confusing while and if. There's also a sequence syntax you can  use in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at `read`:

```
count=0
while read value
do
    echo $value
    ((count++))
done < export_list
```

This looks a lot simpler to me.  Note that the redirection *does* have to be after the `done`.  There are also reasons in Bash not to try `cat export_list | while read value; do … done`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk like this command `awk '{print $0+1}' export_list`

`[root@~ ] # awk '{print $0+1}' export_list 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9`

Comment: ... or `awk '$0++' export_list`